# django 1.6: style django's built in forgot password template

Tags: python, css, django, templates

I'm trying to style django's built in forgot password registration to remove the generic Django green theme and have my own customized them. But I'm unable to do that.

here is the registration/password_reset_form.html with my header and footer that has my bootstrap and custom css files. But they are not reflected in the template. I still see the default django styling.

```
{% include "meddy1/header.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}Reset Password{% endblock %}

<p>Please specify your email address to receive instructions for resetting it.</p>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div style="display:none">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token }}" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
    </div>
     {{ form.email.errors }}
    <p><label for="id_email">E-mail address:</label> {{ form.email }} <input type="submit" value="Reset password" /></p>
</form>

{% include "meddy1/footer.html" %}
```